# Best practice for self made timeout

Tags: c++, c, posix

I am trying to implement a timeout in a C++ method which does some polling. The method currently looks like this (without timeout):

```
do {
    do_something();
    usleep(50);
} while(!is_finished());
```

The solution should have the following properties:

- should survive changes of the system time
- timeout in milliseconds (some jitter is acceptable)
- POSIX compatible
- should not use signals (is part of a library, avoid side effects)
- might use Boost

I am currently thinking about using `clock()` and do something like this:

```
start = clock();

do {
    do_something();
    usleep(50); // TODO: do fancy stuff to avoid waiting after the timeout is reached

    if(clock() - start > timeout * CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) break;
} while(!is_finished());
```

Is this a good solution? I am trying to find the best possible solution as this kind of task seems to come up quite often.

What is considered best practice for this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "POSIX compatible" do you mean POSIX 1003.1b-1993 and POSIX 1003.1i-1995 with Realtime Extensions?

Comment: What I meant was that it should run on POSIX compatible systems.

Answer (score 1):

A timeout precise to milliseconds is out of the reach of any OS that doesn't specifically provide realtime support.

If your system is under heavy load (even temporarily) it's quite possible to have it unresponsive for seconds. Sometimes standard (non-realtime) systems can become very unresponsive for apparently stupid reasons like accessing a CD-Rom device.

Linux has some realtime variations, while for Windows IIRC the only realtime solutions actually have a realtime kernel that is managing the hardware on which a Windows system is run basically "emulated" in a virtual machine.

Comment: I should have written "around milliseconds". Having some jitter is okay for my application. Being able to only set full seconds as timeouts is not.

Comment: The problem is how "hard" is your limit (i.e. ho much of a wreckage would be to miss a deadline: a subtitle in a movie is almost no issue, in a current check it could mean some hardware damage with the machine catching on fire). If the limits are "soft" then `select` seems a reasonable solution and probably 99.99% of the times the delay will be reasonably accurate (but 0.01% of the times they'll be possibly off by quite a bit). I'd be not surprised of the code requiring some little `#ifdef` for different environments.

Comment: My problem is not waiting but keeping track of how much time is spent constantly calling `do_something()` (and waiting). The timeout will be reached after multiple iterations.

Answer (score 1):

`clock` is not the right choice if you want to be portable. On conforming systems this is the CPU time used by your process, on windows it seems to be wall clock time. Also `usleep` is obsolete in current POSIX and you are supposed to use `nanosleep`.

There is one method that could be suitable for a wider range of platforms, `select`. This call has a fifth argument that let's you place a timeout. You can (mis)use that, to wait for network events that you know will never happen, and that then will timeout after a controlled amount of time. From the linux manual on that:

> Some  code  calls `select()` with all three sets empty, `nfds` zero, and a
>   non-`NULL` timeout as a fairly portable way to sleep with subsecond
>          precision.